# How to force postgres docker container to start with new DB

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:3.2.7'
        # command: redis-server --requirepass redispass

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
#            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data


    webserver:
        image: airflow:develop
        depends_on:
            - postgres

        ports:
            - "8080:8080"

        command:
            - webserver
```

After I run `docker-compose up` I see all the services started and seemingly working well. My `webserver` service connects to postgres with the following sqlalchemy connection string: `postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow`

Whenever I kill the composition (with `ctrl-c` or `docker-compose stop`) and then restart it, the data in postgres seems to persist. The reason I believe it persists is because my webserver starts with data from the previous session.

I read the docs for the [postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) and found the `PGDATA` environment variable. I tried to force set it to the default (as seen in the commented line in my docker compose file, but that didn't help. I'm not sure how else to debug why data seems to be persisting between container starts.

How can I force my postgres container to start fresh with each new initialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data was persisted because you did not destroy `postgres` container. You used `docker-compose stop` which only hibernate containers. Use `docker-compose down` instead. It completely destroys containers (but not images).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Does sending `ctrl-c` to the container only hibernate it? Is there a way to get my data to not persist even with hibernation? Maybe a command during startup that wipes the DB if some environment variable is set?

Comment: Your data don't persist as you did not use a volume. Data are in your container only. If you destroy it (with down or rm), the next "up" will create a new container with a new database.